# SwiftUI grid layout using Stack

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

## What I am trying to achieve

Making this grid layout using Stack in SwiftUI
[image: grid layout]

## How I've currently achieved (with Xcode 14.0.1 (14A400))

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ForStackOverflow: View {
    
    let spacerSize: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
            HStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                makeComponent(text: "A")
                makeComponent(text: "B")
                makeComponent(text: "C")
                makeComponent(text: "D")
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                VStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                    HStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                        makeComponent(text: "E")
                        makeComponent(text: "F")
                        makeComponent(text: "G")
                    }

                    HStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                        makeComponent(text: "H")
                        makeComponent(text: "I")
                        makeComponent(text: "J")
                    }
                    
                    HStack(spacing: spacerSize) {
                        makeComponent(text: "K")
                    }
                }
                
                makeComponent(text: "L")
                    // 1. Is there any better way to make the width of L the same width of D?
                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 3) / 4 ) 
            }


        }
    }
    
    func makeComponent(text: String) -> some View {
        // 2. Is there any better way to make the height of L the same height of (G + J + K)?
        let height: CGFloat = text == "L" ? ((80 * 3) + (spacerSize * 2)) : 80

        return Text(text)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: height)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

struct ForStackOverflow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForStackOverflow()
    }
}
```

## Questions

#### 1. Is there any better way to make the width of L the same width of D?

Layout would not look ok without the code below

```swift
let height: CGFloat = text == "L" ? ((80 * 3) + (spacerSize * 2)) : 80
```

It would be like this
[image]

#### 2. Is there any better way to make the height of L the same height of (G + J + K)?

I do not desperately want to solve this one, but if you guys have any suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: If this is a fixed layout and you are using the latest generation of SwiftUI then you should look into [Grid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid)

Comment: Look into the new Layout